# Two-way audio for software ip camera

Tags: linux, camera, gstreamer, raspberry-pi, ip-camera

I am trying to setup a raspberry pi box with a usb camera as a IP Camera that can be viewed from a a generic android IP Camera monitor app. I've found some [examples](http://sanjosetech.blogspot.com/2013/03/web-cam-streaming-from-raspberry-pi-to.html) on how to get the video stream, and that works, but what I also need is two-way audio. This seems to come out of the box in standalone network cameras -- any ideas how that works? I want to set it up in a way compatible with typical network cameras so that my cam can be used by any generic ip camera viewer app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the modern cameras nowadays implement the [ONVIF](http://www.onvif.org) protocol. This protocol specifies that you have a RTSP server that streams audio and video from the camera to the pc, but it also mandates a so called audio backchannel. It's a bit long to explain how it works, check it in the [specs](http://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf).

Comment: Interesting - I've never heard of that before - are there open source implementations that you'd recommend?

Comment: The only opensource software I am aware of is the client that you can find at http://onvifdm.sf.net (which is a client and not a reference camera). Beware, that this project is not related to the ONVIF community, even if the name seems similar. To get more informations, you can go to http://www.onvif.org and register to the developer forum, which is the best place where you can discuss these questions. If correctly remeber, the registration shouldn't require ONVIF membership.

Answer (score 1):

ONVIF is the standard, but you could also install an existing SIP client and do a video/audio VoIP call rather than implementing ONVIF - depends on the long term goals of your project.